# Automatically create a pull request on github with "auto-merge (rebase)" validated?

Tags: github, git-rebase

I'm creating pull requests from my terminal, asking reviewers automatically. I have to manually click on [image: Enable auto-merge (rebase)]

and validate everytime.
Is there a command to check this by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GitHub CLI gh`](https://cli.github.com/) with:

- [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) to create the PR with reviewer
- [`gh pr merge --auto --rebase`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_merge) to automatically rebase only after necessary requirements are met.

That does not change the default, but can be part of a script which would always use `auto-merge (rebase)`.